# How do I do waveform analysis in R or Excel?

Tags: r, excel, waveform

I'm trying to get some information out of a couple of waveforms, which I currently have in the format of a CSV table with the columns: Time, Volume, Pressure, Flow. (The data is the flow/pressure/volume data obtained from a healthcare ventilator.)

I want to get excel / R / another-programme-that-I've-not-yet-thought-of to do the following with the waveform:

1. Break it up into individual breaths - starting with when the pressure starts to rise above a baseline (shortly followed by the flow rising above 0)
2. For each breath, extract:The highest pressure that occurs, the pressure just before the start of the next breath, the lowest pressure that occurs

Does anyone know how to do that, without doing it manually? (It'd mean trawling through a few hours-worth of ventilator data for the project I'm trying to do)

I've attached a copy of the shapes of the waves I'm dealing with, to try to help make more sense.[Pressure & Volume against time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5qGo.png)

My intention is to work out the breath-to-breath variability in maximum, minimum, and baseline pressures.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, I've come up with my own fix using excel.

For each pressure value, I've taken the mean of that value and the two either side of it. I've then compared this to the previous mean. For my data, a change of this mean of more than 1% in either direction identifies the beginning and end of the up- and down-stroke of the pressure curve, and I can identify where in the curve I am based on the absolute value for pressure (the peak should never be lower than the highest baseline for the data I've collected), and for the slopes, the first direction of change of the mean (this smooths out occasionally inconsistent slopes).

I'm then graphing the data, along with the transition points, the calculated phase of the breath, and the breath count, so I can sense-check it visually.

Ged